# Type bigint but expression is of type character varying

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm hoping someone can lend a hand with this:

Trying to insert one row per order_id in a database that is running in RedShift, and sometimes subscription_id contains more than 1 value. This creates duplicate rows, so I figured I would LISTAGG. This is the line:

```
LISTAGG(DISTINCT CAST(script.subscription_id AS VARCHAR), ',') AS subscription_id
```

The **subscription_id** column is an **int8** and after giving me the character varying error, I tried to `CAST`; but for some reason I cannot do it. Does `LISTAGG` do not support this type of nested `CAST`? If not, is there a wasy to actually achieve this?

ORIGINAL:

```
order_id subscription_id
1 123
2 124
3 125
1 126
2 127
```

IDEAL:

```
order_id subscription_id
1 123,126
2 124,127
3 125
```

Both columns are of int8.

Comment: Redshift is similar to postgres right? If `subscription_id` is `int8`, then it can only hold `int8`, not varchar, and not an array of int8. You will have to change your table's structure to store the data like that.

Comment: Hi 404, thanks for the comment. Yes, RedShift is PostGres.
I thought about changing the type of the column, but what do you think I can do in the situation that I do not have the privileges to update the column type?

Comment: If you can't change the table at all then you can't store the data like that and instead need to store 1 row per order/subscription combination. Then when reading it back you can group them together. In standard postgres you would do `SELECT order_id, ARRAY_AGG(subscription_id) FROM table WHERE ... GROUP BY order_id`